# Onvif - GetDigitalInputs ends with Namespace Error

Tags: soap, onvif

I'm having trouble getting digital inputs from a camera that uses ONVIF as a communication protocol. I know, that the camera has 2 digital inputs and it is anonymously accessible without logging in.

I'm using action `GetDigitalInputs` from this WSDL: https://www.onvif.org/ver10/deviceio.wsdl. Some other actions work. For example I'm able to use `GetRelayOutputs` successfully.

Here is the request I'm sending to the camera to deviceIO service URL (`http://ipaddress/onvif/deviceio_service`). Device IO service URL was obtained from a result of `GetCapabilities` action:

```xml
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
    <s:Body>
      <GetDigitalInputs xmlns="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/deviceIO/wsdl" />
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

And here is the response

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding" xmlns:ter="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/error">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <SOAP-ENV:Fault>
            <SOAP-ENV:Code>
                <SOAP-ENV:Value>SOAP-ENV:Sender</SOAP-ENV:Value>
                <SOAP-ENV:Subcode>
                    <SOAP-ENV:Value>ter:Namespace</SOAP-ENV:Value>
                </SOAP-ENV:Subcode>
            </SOAP-ENV:Code>
            <SOAP-ENV:Reason>
                <SOAP-ENV:Text xml:lang="en">Namespace Error</SOAP-ENV:Text>
            </SOAP-ENV:Reason>
            <SOAP-ENV:Node>http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope/node/ultimateReceiver</SOAP-ENV:Node>
            <SOAP-ENV:Role>http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope/node/ultimateReceiver</SOAP-ENV:Role>
        </SOAP-ENV:Fault>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I've tried to change namespace of the `GetDigitalInputs` to `http://www.onvif.org/ver10/deviceio/wsdl` and `http://www.onvif.org/ver10/device/wsdl`. Both didn't work.

I've tried using [Onvif Device Test Tool](http://www.happytimesoft.com/download.html), which has the same issue as I have.

I'm having the same issue with action `GetSerialPorts`. Both on multiple different Bosch cameras.

Answer (score 0):

What about the following XML?

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
    <s:Body>
      <tmd:GetDigitalInputs xmlns:tmd="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/deviceIO/wsdl" />
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Comment: Thank your for the suggestion, but this is not working. It is just an explicitly used namespace alias instead of an implicit use of the same namespace. - Nevertheless I tried it - no luck.